# How do I use this regex with grep?

Tags: grep, regular-expression, words

I'm new to regex and found a command on a regex tutorial/test site that will allow me to search for 3 consecutive consonants. The only problem is I can't figure out how to use it with grep. Would someone help me out? I'm trying to search a word list text file using:

`(?:([bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxzy])(?!.{1,2}\1)){3}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Regex pattern you have contains:

- Non-capturing group, `(?:)`
- Zero width negative lookahead, `(?!)`

which are only supported by `grep` with PCRE, Perl Compatible Regular Expression (`-P`)

So you need `grep -P`, and to capture only the matched portion, `-o`:

```
% grep -Po '(?:([bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxzy])(?!.{1,2}\1)){3}' <<<'foobarspfb'
rsp
```

Comment: Thanks, will except answer when it allows in a few mins. Any chance you can tell me how to make it list the whole word if it finds the pattern instead of just the pattern?

Comment: @Jake You want to match whole words only?

Comment: no I just want to list the words that contain 3 or more consonants in a row

Comment: @Jake ummmm, sorry I don't understand. It would be better if you ask this as a new question with an input chunk and your desired output from that.

Comment: Sorry I'll try to re-explain. I have a list of words that is too big for me to manually look through. I want to print out to my terminal each word in the list that is spelled with 3 or more non-vowel characters in a row. For example: it should print 'angst' because that has 4 consonants in a row (ngst), but it shouldn't print 'paper' because that only has 1 consonant in a row.